# How to replace HTML element with JavaScript element or clone of it?

Tags: javascript, html, replace, textbox

How to replace HTML element with JavaScript element or clone of it (without deleting the HTML element)?
I'm wasted a lot of time on trying to make JavaScript that will:

1. Clone HTML textbox / Create new JS textbox
2. Replace the HTML textbox with JS textbox without deleting the HTML textbox / Put Clone of HTML textbox on existing HTML textbox.

I can't find the solution of this.

Here's code -> 
I'm getting `[object HTMLInputElement]` in output...

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
  <td><input class="inputtext" name="first" id="first" tabindex="1" type="text"></td>
  <td><input class="inputtext" name="second" id="second" tabindex="1" type="text"></td>

  </body>
</html>

  </body>
</html>

<script>
function replaceTargetWith( targetID, html ){
  var i, div, elm, last, target = document.getElementById(targetID);
  div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = html;
  i = div.childNodes.length;
  last = target;
  while(i--){
    target.parentNode.insertBefore((elm = div.childNodes[i]), last);
    last = elm;
  }
  /// remove the target.
  target.parentNode.removeChild(target);
}
</script>


<script>


var p = document.getElementById("first");
    var p_prime = first.cloneNode(true);
    p_prime.id = "first123"
    p_prime.name = "first123"
    p_prime.value = "testtest"

    document.getElementById("first").appendChild(p_prime)

document.getElementById('first').value='emailtype@gmail.com' ;
document.getElementById('second').value='LecimyTutaj' ;

window.onload = function(){
  replaceTargetWith('first', document.getElementById('first123'));  
}

</script>
```

I would like to Hide an existing HTML textbox behind new JavaScript created Textbox, or  clone of it created by Javascript without deleting it. :) Sorry if I wrote something wrong.

Comment: Please put in your question what the input and output look like; i.e. show us the original HTML, and the new HTML the way you would like it to look.

Comment: Don't put code into comments.  As you can see, they are unreadable.  Edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at a computer, so it's hard to add code samples to help you but in general... make an HTML model and give it a `display:none` in CSS (you won't be using this chunk explicitly so don't put any values in it... it's just here to copy and paste from). Give it an id like "myModel".  Then you can [cloneNode(true)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode) on that model and add it as many times as you like as a child of some container. Fill these pasted instances with whatever values you desire.

If no one gives you more useful help in the next few hours, I'll add a code sample when I'm somewhere other than my phone.

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming you want to add more input fields dynamically. You will need some sort of trigger, then you can use the append function using JQuery.

```
$("someBtnToTrigger").click(function(){
        $("#someForm > tbody:last").append("<td><input class='test123' name='test123'       
id='test123' tabindex='1' type='text'></td>");
        return false;
```

Comment: OP didn't request jQuery and you're making totally unwarranted assumptions about the nature of the context and whether or not there's a clickable trigger. -1

Comment: no, he wants to hide the first one then make a new one. this is the easiest way. All he has to do is hide the first input. then he is done

Comment: If you're using jQuery there's a much easier way `$('#target').after($('#target').clone())'`

Comment: I would like to use JavaScript only, without jQuery. I trying "Charlie Liu" method and I can't make it works... :/

Comment: @CharlieLiu, I would agree that the mess you're offering him would indeed mean "he's done", but not in the way you mean it. He's "done" as an applicant for any job I'd hire him to do. He's "done" as a qualified developer.

Comment: @GeniaS. Can You help me with this piece of code? I would like to use only JavaScript. I'm really newbie and can't understand a lot of things so far. Please help me, If you can modify my code somehow and make it works...

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do.  Which html elements are you trying to clone and why?